# ODBC Microsoft Access Error: Syntax error in update, delete statement

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I am writing a java program which connects with Ms Access using ODBC-JDBC Driver.
The Select and Insert Into Statement are working correctly but delete and update statement are showing syntax error. I have tried all possible solutions but nothing seems to work. Can someone suggest what is wrong with my syntax?

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Lab{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Test");

    Statement st=conn.createStatement();

    String sql="SELECT * FROM Playlist ";

    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println("\n "+rs.getString("S No")+"\t"+rs.getString("Song name")+"\t"+rs.getString("Album")+"\t"+rs.getString("Singer"));
    }

    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Playlist"
            + " VALUES (6, 'Nebraa', 'WesteStars', 'Bre')");

    sql = "update Playlist " 
        + " set Song name='Nebula' " 
        + " where S No=6";
    st.executeUpdate(sql);

    sql = "DELETE FROM Playlist " +
                   "WHERE S No = 6 ";   
    st.executeUpdate(sql);

    conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names `Song Name` and `S No` have space so enclose in `[ ]` delimiters - `[Song Name]` and `[S No]`. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in database naming convention.